# Como criar uma máscara para moeda brasileira com limite de caracteres?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um código que formata os valores para moeda brasileira (BRL) que funciona muito bem, porém preciso que ela limite a quantidade de números até 15 dígitos. Onde tenho que colocar essa validação?

```js
// parâmetros da função moeda (pelo que entendi)
// a = objeto do input // e = separador milésimo
// r = separador decimal // t = evento

function moeda(a, e, r, t) {
   let n = "",
      h = j = 0,
      u = tamanho2 = 0,
      l = ajd2 = "",
      o = window.Event ? t.which : t.keyCode;
   if (13 == o || 8 == o)
      return !0;
   if (n = String.fromCharCode(o),
      -1 == "0123456789".indexOf(n))
      return !1;
   for (u = a.value.length,
      h = 0; h < u && ("0" == a.value.charAt(h) || a.value.charAt(h) == r); h++);
   for (l = ""; h < u; h++) - 1 != "0123456789".indexOf(a.value.charAt(h)) && (l += a.value.charAt(h));
   if (l += n, 0 == (u = l.length) && (a.value = ""), 1 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + "0" + l), 2 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + l), u > 2) {
      for (ajd2 = "",
         j = 0,
         h = u - 3; h >= 0; h--)
         3 == j && (ajd2 += e,
            j = 0),
         ajd2 += l.charAt(h),
         j++;
      for (a.value = "",
         tamanho2 = ajd2.length,
         h = tamanho2 - 1; h >= 0; h--)
         a.value += ajd2.charAt(h);
      a.value += r + l.substr(u - 2, u)
   }
   return !1
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
   <li>
      <label>Valor Renda no Período (R$)</label><br />
      <input type="text" required maxlength="15" style="border: solid 0.5px #000; width: 200px;" onkeypress="return(moeda(this,'.',',',event))">
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A variável que você procura é "a", com o código"  a.value.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'')   " você obtém os números, aí precisa tratar isso.-

Comment: function FormatCurrency(valor) {
    valor = valor + ''
    valor = parseInt(valor.replace(/[\D]+/g, ''))
    valor = valor + ''
    if (valor.length === 1) valor = valor.replace(/([0-9]{1})/, ',0$1')
    else valor = valor.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ',$1')

    if (valor.length > 6) {
      valor = valor.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, '.$1,$2')
    }
    if (valor.length > 10) {
      valor = valor.replace(/([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2})$/g, '.$1.$2,$3')
    }

    valor = 'R$ ' + valor
    if (valor == 'R$ NaN') valor = ''
    return valor as string
  }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloque no início da função um `if` com o `replace` indicado pelo amigo @Null nos comentários, acrescentando o método `.length` que irá retornar o número de dígitos no input.

Basta apenas `a.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').length`, onde a regex `/[^\d]/g` irá eliminar tudo o que não for número. Então você irá comparar com o atributo `maxlength`:

```
if(a.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').length > a.getAttribute("maxlength")-1)
    return
```

O código `a.getAttribute("maxlength")` irá retornar `15` (do atributo `maxlength="15"`) subtraindo `1`, ou seja, se a quantidade de números no input for maior que `14`, irá entrar no `return` do `if` saindo da função, e assim permitindo que se digite no máximo 15 números.

Veja:

```js
function moeda(a, e, r, t) {

   if(a.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').length > a.getAttribute("maxlength")-1)
    return

   let n = ""
     , h = j = 0
     , u = tamanho2 = 0
     , l = ajd2 = ""
     , o = window.Event ? t.which : t.keyCode;
   if (13 == o || 8 == o)
       return !0;
   if (n = String.fromCharCode(o),
   -1 == "0123456789".indexOf(n))
       return !1;
   for (u = a.value.length,
   h = 0; h < u && ("0" == a.value.charAt(h) || a.value.charAt(h) == r); h++)
       ;
   for (l = ""; h < u; h++)
       -1 != "0123456789".indexOf(a.value.charAt(h)) && (l += a.value.charAt(h));
   if (l += n,
   0 == (u = l.length) && (a.value = ""),
   1 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + "0" + l),
   2 == u && (a.value = "0" + r + l),
   u > 2) {
       for (ajd2 = "",
       j = 0,
       h = u - 3; h >= 0; h--)
           3 == j && (ajd2 += e,
           j = 0),
           ajd2 += l.charAt(h),
           j++;
       for (a.value = "",
       tamanho2 = ajd2.length,
       h = tamanho2 - 1; h >= 0; h--)
           a.value += ajd2.charAt(h);
       a.value += r + l.substr(u - 2, u)
       
   }
   return !1
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
   <li>
      <label>Valor Renda no Período (R$)</label><br/>
      <input type="text" required maxlength="15" style="border: solid 0.5px #000; width: 200px;" onkeypress="return(moeda(this,'.',',',event))">
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfeito, cara, puxa, funcionou perfeitamente!!! Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Códigozinho apesar de grande, tá funcional. Valeu, Lopes Gabiroba. Rs

Answer (score 6):

Uma outra alternativa com um código menor.

```js
const mascaraMoeda = (event) => {
  const onlyDigits = event.target.value
    .split("")
    .filter(s => /\d/.test(s))
    .join("")
    .padStart(3, "0")
  const digitsFloat = onlyDigits.slice(0, -2) + "." + onlyDigits.slice(-2)
  event.target.value = maskCurrency(digitsFloat)
}

const maskCurrency = (valor, locale = 'pt-BR', currency = 'BRL') => {
  return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
    style: 'currency',
    currency
  }).format(valor)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onInput="mascaraMoeda(event);" />
```

Comment: Não é exatamente "o que o autor quer", mas ta de parabéns pela refatoração do código, reduziu bastante as linhas e conforme o seguimento da ES6.. massa!

Answer (score 3):

O problema de usar `maxlength` é que ele acaba sendo "ignorado". Afinal, se você quer um número com no máximo 15 dígitos (por exemplo, `123456789012345`), o valor com máscara será `1.234.567.890.123,45`, ou seja, 20 caracteres.

**E o JavaScript aceita que você coloque um valor com mais caracteres que o indicado por `maxlength`**. Exemplo:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#valor');
// setar um valor com mais de 15 caracteres
input.value = '12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890';

// maxlength continua sendo 15
console.log(input.maxLength); // 15
// mas o valor tem mais que 15 caracteres
console.log(input.value);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="valor" maxlength="15" />
```

Por isso, se o valor já for `123.456.789,09` (ou seja, 14 caracteres), e eu digitar mais um número (por exemplo, `8`), a máscara será aplicada e o valor ficará com 16 caracteres (`1.234.567.890,98`). E depois disso não conseguirei digitar mais nada, mesmo que o valor só tenha 12 dígitos (eu só consigo setar um valor com mais caracteres via JavaScript - digitando até daria, como está em outra resposta, mas ela usa o evento `keypress`, que como veremos adiante, está obsoleto).

Ou seja, não adianta ter o `maxlength` se você pode setar qualquer valor maior que isso. E de qualquer forma, você não quer verificar o tamanho total do campo, e sim a quantidade de dígitos. Colocar `maxlength` igual a 15 só deixa o código mais confuso na minha opinião, já que na prática (segundo as regras que você mesmo definiu) ele pode ter mais de 15 caracteres.

Na verdade o que podemos fazer é usar `maxlength` igual a 20 (que é a quantidade de caracteres necessários para formatar 15 dígitos), o que impediria de digitar mais caso já esteja "cheio", e na função de máscara garantimos que desses 20 caracteres, no máximo 15 sejam dígitos.

---

Para que o campo possa ter a informação de quantos dígitos ele aceita, uma alternativa é colocar esta informação no seu [*dataset*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). Por exemplo, para ter no máximo 15 dígitos:

```html
<input type="text" id="valor" data-max-digits="15" maxlength="20" />
```

Assim, basta pegar esta informação na hora de verificar:

```js
// usa vírgula como separador decimal, ponto como separador de milhar, sempre com 2 casas decimais
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });

function mask(e) {
    const input = e.target;
    // elimina tudo que não é dígito
    input.value = input.value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
    if (input.value.length === 0) // se não tem nada preenchido, não tem o que fazer
        return;
    // verifica se ultrapassou a quantidade máxima de dígitos (pegar o valor no dataset)
    const maxDigits = parseInt(input.dataset.maxDigits);
    if (input.value.length > maxDigits) {
        // O que fazer nesse caso? Decidi pegar somente os primeiros dígitos
        input.value = input.value.substring(0, maxDigits);
    }
    // lembrando que o valor é a quantidade de centavos, então precisa dividir por 100
    input.value = formatter.format(parseInt(input.value) / 100);
}

document.querySelector('#valor').addEventListener('input', mask);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="valor" data-max-digits="15" maxlength="20" />
```

Usei um [`NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) que formata os números com 2 casas decimais, além de usar os separadores corretos (vírgula para os decimais, ponto para os milhares - isso é controlado pelo *locale*, que no caso é o valor `pt-BR`, que [corresponde ao português do Brasil](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/pt-BR/index.html)). Desta forma ele não exibe o "R$" antes, mas se quiser inclui-lo, basta fazer [como a outra resposta indicou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/503943/112052):

```js
// Use isso se quiser que o valor tenha o "R$" antes dos números (mas aí precisa aumentar o maxlength para que inclua o "R$")
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
```

Depois, eu removo tudo que não é dígito (`\D+`, ou seja, um ou mais caracteres que não sejam dígitos), e só depois eu vejo se ultrapassou o limite máximo de dígitos (cuja quantidade está indicada no *dataset*).

Por fim, antes de formatar, eu divido o valor por 100, afinal o que temos são apenas dígitos que correspondem à quantidade total de centavos. Não precisa manipular strings como as outras respostas fizeram, basta ajustar o valor numérico que o `NumberFormat` faz o resto para você.

Eu não usei o evento `keypress` (que [segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) está obsoleto e não deve ser mais usado), e no lugar coloquei o evento `input`, que detecta não apenas se algo é digitado, mas também se é colado via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, ou se algum número é apagado (testei a [solução da outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/421316/112052) no Chrome, por exemplo, e ela não refaz a máscara se um dígito é apagado, e nem se fizer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> de um número), etc.

Aliás, se você por exemplo fizer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> de um valor como `12345678901234567890`, eu pego somente os 15 primeiros dígitos (é pra isso que serve o `if (input.value.length > maxDigits)`). Pois em casos de *copy-paste* todo o valor é jogado no `input` de uma vez, então eu tenho que eliminar os dígitos a mais (o que não ocorre se você só digita um número por vez, pois neste caso a máscara é aplicada logo depois de cada tecla e não cai no `if`). Assim eu garanto que nunca vai ultrapassar a quantidade máxima de dígitos.

O `if (input.value.length > maxDigits)` também serve para tratar outras situações, como por exemplo:

- o valor atual do `input` (após aplicar a máscara) é `12.345.678,90` (10 dígitos)
- eu copio (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) o valor `9999999999` (de um outro programa qualquer)
- posiciono o cursor no início (antes do `1`)
- faço <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. O valor do `input` passa a ser `999999912.345.678,90` (ele limita usando o valor do `maxlength`, por isso que nem todos os `9` são colados - **testei no Chrome, não sei se todos os *browsers* farão da mesma forma**). Depois de remover tudo que não é dígito, mas antes de aplicar a máscara, o valor passa a ser `99999991234567890` (17 dígitos), e por fim, depois de pegar somente os 15 primeiros dígitos e aplicar a máscara, fica `9.999.999.123.456,78`

---

<sup>Obs: aceitar 15 dígitos significa que o valor máximo do campo é `9.999.999.999.999,99` (quase 10 trilhões de reais), ou seja, um valor **maior que o [PIB brasileiro de 2020](https://www.google.com/search?q=brazil+gdp+2020)**. E no seu HTML o `label` do campo é "Valor Renda no Período", então será que 15 dígitos não seria exagero? Enfim...</sup>